# how to do open or close envelope transition, Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, core-animation

My target is to do fold and unfold an envelope using animation ( like the one we are having in linkedin app ). I am using 2 provided images below :

[envelope001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3AkP.png)

[envelope002](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fOk4.png)

So the blue one (named envelope001) is used to show unread email and the grey (evelope002) is for read. What I am doing is

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"envelope00%.1ld.png",(long)i];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:celName];
    [cels addObject:img];
}
self.myImage.animationImages = arr;
self.myImage.animationDuration = 1.6;
[self.myImage startAnimating];
```

However, the transition looks awkward.I am still looking for another solution to improve.
All comments are welcomed here
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is only rotating, you can do animations by changing attributes of the view. So probably not very practical to do so.

I also worked on customise loading animations before. My experience is that you can supply more images. I think the more the better. Maybe try more than 5 photos so that you can have smoother animation.

But the download side is that you may need to PS more envelop photos.